# How to update many records in one batch in ActiveRecord ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, activerecord, castle-activerecord

Suppose I need to update many records in my database, I'm using Castle Active Record and doing this:

```
List<Class> objects = Class.GetFew();
foreach (Class object in objects) {
    object.Property = ...
    object.Update() // I don't want to do this 
}
// Can I do it in one batch here?
```

I want Active record to do it in one DB call, hope my question is clear, can I do it and how?

Thanks

Comment: `object.Property` will have the same value in all objects?

Comment: @linepogl, no, different, every `object` is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NHibernate's DML-style HQL operations](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct). Use [Execute in ActiveRecord](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/hql.html#ExecCallback) to gain access to the NHibernate session.